# IIS Express 502 error in vs 2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, iis, asp.net-core-2.0

When I create new .NET Core 2.0 project in Visual Studio 2017, I am getting an error when I try to run IIS Express:

> "Unable to start process C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe. The web server request failed with status code 502, Bad Gateway"

[image]

I try:

- Visual Studio restart
- Machine restart
- .Net SDK reinstall
- Run Visual Studio as admin
- Clean project (delete `.vs`, `bin` and obj folders)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you solve yours?

Answer (score 1):

Same after upgrading to VS 15.6.4. Workaround in the meantime to keep working: click on IIS Express and change to project name, that will start the server in a console.

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate the issue, are you able to run dotnet core application with default template.

Add Current logged in user in IIS_Users Group and try to run the application.